# How to use submit button in grails with if-else statement?

Tags: grails, button, groovy, tags

I am now currently working on a `grails project`. I have a problem with my `<g:submitButton>` tag, and I am using a web flow. What I wanted to do is to proceed on the next page using `<g:submitButton>` if the input from the user is 1, while display a pop up window with options OK and Cancel buttons if the input is 0. If Ok button is clicked, the user will be redirected into a certain page, same through if the Cancel button is clicked.

Have anyone tried this?

Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you need some javascript in your form tag for this functionality. Search for “html form onsubmit“ and you'll find some good resources.

Comment: But I guess you have to. Otherwise you'll have an ugly server roundtrip.